# How to get spring boot to load properties from mounted volume in kubernetes?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Sadly, the documentations is really really lacking in this regard. No real example, only pointing to properties which apparently don't work.

What I have so far:

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  ...
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      enabled: true
      config:
        paths: /etc/config/application.yml
        enabled: true
        enable-api: false
  ...
```

**configmap.yml**

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: service-config
data:
  application.yml: |-
    spring:
      datasource:
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:31871/postgresdb
  ...
```

**Deployment.yml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/config
              name: app-config-map
              readOnly: true
              subPath: ""
      volumes:
        - name: app-config-map
          configMap:
            defaultMode: 384
            name: service-config
            optional: false
```

But spring crashes with `Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.`

I've tried to change config.paths to all kinds of paths, rename to .yaml (because one document said it searches for .yaml as key) and much more. But it doesn't even seem to pickup the existance of any mounted property.

I'm just lost with that. Any idea / example that does work?

Comment: What documentation are you referring to? You don’t need to use Spring Cloud Kubernetes for this as Spring Boot supports it as described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-files-configtree

Comment: @AndyWilkinson https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#configmap-propertysource. "Another option for using ConfigMap instances is to mount them into the Pod by running the Spring Cloud Kubernetes application and having Spring Cloud Kubernetes read them from the file system. This behavior is controlled by the spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.paths property." This just doesn't work at all for me

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Interestingly config.import leads to the very same issue

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot 2.4 or later, I wouldn’t bother using Spring Cloud Kubernetes for this as it isn’t needed. Beyond the examples in the Boot docs, start.spring.io is deployed on Kubernetes. Its config for that is [here](https://github.com/spring-io/start.spring.io/tree/main/ci/config).

Comment: I’d double-check that K8S is mounting things as you expect in the container.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I did, when I do kubectl exec ... ls /etc/config I get application.yml. So exactly as I'd expect. But SPRING_CONFIG_IMPORT isn't using it whatsoever. Nor is the kubernetes extension. Also using cat I can see the url in there

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I'm also a bit confused about the configtree. E.g. spring.datasource.password is mounted as a file named "spring.datasource.password". Configtree would expect it to be in config/spring/datasource/password. That would mean a 1:1 map of item paths for every entry. That seems a like a lot of additional work?

Comment: It depends on what type of volume mount you are using. The docs I linked to previously describe both options.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I dont know any volume mount that would convert the a.b.c to a/b/c. Interestingly, configtree is able to work with that anyways (so files called a.b.c). Feel free to post the config.import as an answer. Got it to work. The k8s extension still doesn't like it though

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot volume injected configuration properties : [Without using spring cloud kubernetes] -- Relying on Spring Boot 2.4+ configuration loading features.

In your application.properties, specify following

```
    spring.config.import=configtree:/etc/config/,file:/etc/config/application.properties
```

Your kubernetes configMap should look like following,

```
$ kubectl get configmaps inventory-service -o yaml

apiVersion: v1
data:
  application.properties: |

    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST:db}:${DB_PORT:3306}/bootappdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER}
    spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    ....
    ...
```

And you Pod Yaml manifest should include the following,

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: inventory-service
  namespace: bootapp
  labels:
    app: inventory-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: inventory-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: inventory-service
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 20
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: inventory-service
      containers:
        - name: inventory-service
          image: inventory-service:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          readinessProbe:
              httpGet:
                port: 8040
                path: /inventory
              initialDelaySeconds: 30
              periodSeconds: 15
              failureThreshold: 3
              timeoutSeconds: 10
              successThreshold: 1
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
                port: 8040
                path: /inventory
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 15
            failureThreshold: 3
            timeoutSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "512Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
            requests:
              memory: "256Mi"
              cpu: "250m"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8040
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/config
              name: config-volume
              readOnly: true
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 50%
      maxUnavailable: 20%
  replicas: 1
  minReadySeconds: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 300
  revisionHistoryLimit: 5
```